# Routing with multiple app on same page

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm building an app that contains multiple apps.

Typically:

```
<body>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

`app-header` contains `LoginComponent`, `RegisterComponent`. `app-root` contains `HomeComponent`. The `AppRoot` is the master app where `<router-outlet>` is located. `AppHeader` is just the `nav`, basically.

Why am I using 2 apps? Because I need `app-header` on 3 different project where `app-header` will be exactly the same. (Maybe this is not the best solution though?)

My issue is handling routes between those two separate apps.

This is my `app-header` routing:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
];
```

This is my `app-root` routing:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

The thing is, having 2 routes causes problems. If I click on the Login `nav` button, it will correctly lead me to the `LoginComponent` and the URL will change to `http://localhost:4200/login` **but** the `HomeComponent` will stay, leading to this:

[image]

Both `Home` and `Login` components are displaying, even though URL is `/login`. That is because `app-root` is unaware of the url's modification as `/login` is part of `app-header`.

I believe the solution would be to use only one `appRoutes` that will manage both `app-root` and `app-header` components routing. Like so:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
];
```

However, `LoginComponent` and `RegisterComponent` don't exist on this current app so it just won't work.

So the solution is either manage to make it work with a master `appRoutes`, or two different `appRoutes` for both `app-header` and `app-root` that will both be aware of url's modifications.

Comment: *maybe this is not the best solution though?*: indeed: you should simply make a library, and possibly bundle these components in an angular module, that you can import in your three apps. Just like ng-bootstrap, or angular-material, or any other angular library does.

Comment: Alright! Could you give me a link about making a Angular library and implement it? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any such tutorial. I'm waiting for angular CLI to support this scenario.